# apex: query from a list

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I'm using apex and salesforce stuff. I have a list of some accounts and now I need to create another list of the accounts that are valid. so imagine this is the list:

```
 List<Account__c> accounts = [Select Name, Status From Account__c];
 .
 .
 .
 // now I need a new list with all the accounts that the status == 'valid'

 //this is not working
 List<Account__c> accounts = [Select Name, Status From :accounts
                              where status == 'valid'];
```

Is there a way to get the list ?

Comment: Question was answered here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/66674/17190

Answer (score 0):

Please check below query :

List accounts = [Select Name, Status From Account__c];
 .
 .
 .
 // now you need a new list with all the accounts that the status == 'valid'

List accounts = [Select Name, Status From Account
                              where status = 'valid' AND id IN: accounts];

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Account__c> accounts = [Select Id, Name, Status From Account__c];
List<Account__c> otherAccounts = [Select Name, Status From Account__c where Id IN :accounts AND status = 'valid'];
```